# Probability of Runs/Straights with Variable Amount of Polyhedral Dice

Tags: probability

## The Problem and Possible Solution

I am making a general formula for calculating the probability for a run/[straight](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight) of length *R*, given *R* number of regular polyhedral dice, each of which has a number of faces *d*. I derived the following formula and want to see if I have done this correctly:

$$P(run) = \frac{(d-R+1)(R!)}{d^R}$$

**Am I right**? Assumed are that R and d are integers; R can be 2, 3, 4, or 5; and d can be 4, 6, 8, 10, or 12. Additionally, all the dice rolled are the same size and only the minimum amount needed for each run are rolled.

## My Method for Derivation

I got the numerator by looking at the results of rolling Rd4 and Rd6, with R equal to 2, 3, and 4. This would be out of the total set of results, which is just $d^R$. I had assumed this would be enough to extrapolate out to higher die and run sizes, and initial calculations seem correct.

## Context

The motivation here is to make a set of poker-like "hand" rankings, but with a variable amount of polyhedral dice. Figuring out doubles is pretty easy, it's the straights that are giving (or gave) me trouble!

Comment: For those who care to know more or are suspicious of the inputs, this *is* for a table-top RPG. Yes, it's for my own fun unless it's **really** good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, I think that you nailed it.

The denominator does reflect that there are $R$ dice, each of which has $d$ possibilities of showing.

Assuming that each die contains the faces that represent the elements in $\{1,2,\cdots,d\}$, the lowest possible and highest possible straights are:

- $\{1,2,\cdots,R\}$
- $\{1 + (d-R), 2 + (d-R), \cdots, R + (d-R)\}.$

So, the bottom end of the straight is an element in $\{1,2,\cdots,[1 + (d-R)]\}$, which has $[1 + (d-R)]$ elements.

So, the first factor in the numerator is validated.  The second factor represents that (for example) the combination of dice giving $\{1,2,\cdots,R\}$ yields $(R!)$ permutations among the $(R)$ dice.